# Not reading XML elements with namespace

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I've got the following XML document information:

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA_SDTC.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
  <component>
    <structuredBody>
      <component>
        <section>
          <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.45" />
          <title>Instructions</title>
          <text>
            <paragraph>Putting instructions into the node to read out into the text area.</paragraph>
          </text>
        </section>
      </component>
    </structuredBody>
  </component>
</Document>
```

I have to have the XML document loaded by a VB.NET page in order to look for this particular information and put the contents of the paragraph node into a text area form field on a web page. This was working with no problem, but the document root had some namespace information added and now it's not working. This is the VB.NET code:

```
m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("Document/component/structuredBody/component/section")
For Each m_node In m_nodelist
  If m_node("title").InnerText = "Instructions" Then
    Dim Instructions As String = m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("Document/component/structuredBody/component/section[title='Instructions']/text/paragraph").InnerText
    txtInstructions.Text = Replace(patientInstructions, "<br>", Chr(10) & Chr(13))
    hfInstructionsOld.Value = Replace(patientInstructions, "<br>", Chr(10) & Chr(13))
  End If
Next
```

I presume it was working before because the root node didn't have a namespace defined. Now that it does. I don't know how to change the VB.NET code to account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a default namespace is now defined on the root element, all of the elements belong to that namespace, by default.  When using XPath (as you are doing with `SelectNodes` and `SelectSingleNodes`), you must always explicitly specify the namespace.  There is no way, with XPath, to specify a default namespace which is always used when no namespace is explicitly specified.  Here's how to do it:

```
Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:hl7-org:v3")
m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("x:Document/x:component/x:structuredBody/x:component/x:section", nsmgr)
For Each m_node In m_nodelist
    If m_node("title").InnerText = "Instructions" Then
        Dim Instructions As String = m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("x:Document/x:component/x:structuredBody/x:component/x:section[x:title='Instructions']/x:text/x:paragraph", nsmgr).InnerText
        txtInstructions.Text = Replace(patientInstructions, "<br>", Chr(10) & Chr(13))
        hfInstructionsOld.Value = Replace(patientInstructions, "<br>", Chr(10) & Chr(13))
    End If
Next
```

Or, if you want it to just dynamically get the namespace from the root element, you can do this:

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", m_xmld.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
```